How serve the content of a website in CDN + route 53 using my cloudflare domain
I had a domain in Namecheap linked with the URL of a test project deployed in AWS. I used S3 + Cloudfront and Route 53 for this project. It was working fine, when I accessed xisart.com it served my content hosted in AWS. but I decided to move my domain name to Cloudflare, and in Cloudflare, I put this configuration

but it is not working. it shows "This site can’t be reached"
in AWS route 53 I have this

so basically, I want to access my project by redirecting the page to my Cloudflare domain

You can execute following steps:

Make sure you can open your Cloudfront URL directly in your browser: xxx.cloudfront.net
Update your Cloudflare CNAME entry from Proxied to DNS Only. This will unsure that your requests goes directly to Cloudfront and are not processed by Cloudflare.
Validate that the certificate on your Cloudfront environment is properly installed. If there is no certificate, create a new one. When you will be asked to add DNS record validation, create them in Cloudflare directly.

Route53 is useless in your case as you're using Cloudfront directly from Cloudflare.
If you want to have Cloudflare -> Route53 -> Cloudfront, you will have to:

Remove the CNAME Cloudflare entry.
Add NS entries in Cloudflare coming from your Route53 NS entries values .

